# LaTeX booktabs package cmidline gets pushed up if another column heading requires more than one line

Tags: tables, sectioning, booktabs

Compiling the following code shows the problem. The first table is given in the `booktabs` documentation. The column following the `cmidrule`-spanned columns requires a single line of text. The second table is the same, but the final column requires three lines of text. The `cmidrule` gets pushed up. This is not what we want. How to keep the cmidline where it belongs, just above the column headings it spans?

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

1. booktabs example: Last column head fits on single line

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{}llr@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Item} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-2}
Animal & Description & Price (\$)\\
\midrule
Gnat      & per gram  & 13.65 \\
          & each      &  0.01 \\
Gnu       & stuffed   & 92.50 \\
Emu       & stuffed   & 33.33 \\
Armadillo & frozen    &  8.99 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

2. Modification: Last column head requires 3 lines

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{}llr@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Item} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-2}
Animal & Description & \parbox[b][][b]{1.40cm}{\raggedleft Price\\in\\Dollars}\\
\midrule
Gnat      & per gram  & 13.65 \\
          & each      &  0.01 \\
Gnu       & stuffed   & 92.50 \\
Emu       & stuffed   & 33.33 \\
Armadillo & frozen    &  8.99 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can hide the height of the heading and then adjust with a zero width rule:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

1. booktabs example: Last column head fits on single line

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{}llr@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Item} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-2}
Animal & Description & Price (\$)\\
\midrule
Gnat      & per gram  & 13.65 \\
          & each      &  0.01 \\
Gnu       & stuffed   & 92.50 \\
Emu       & stuffed   & 33.33 \\
Armadillo & frozen    &  8.99 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

2. Modification: Last column head requires 3 lines

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{}llr@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Item} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-2}
Animal & Description & \parbox[b][][b]{1.40cm}{\raggedleft Price\\in\\Dollars}\\
\midrule
Gnat      & per gram  & 13.65 \\
          & each      &  0.01 \\
Gnu       & stuffed   & 92.50 \\
Emu       & stuffed   & 33.33 \\
Armadillo & frozen    &  8.99 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

3. Modification: 

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{}llr@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Item}&\rule{0pt}{1.3\normalbaselineskip} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-2}
Animal & Description & 
\smash{\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}Price\\in\\Dollars\end{tabular}}\\
\midrule
Gnat      & per gram  & 13.65 \\
          & each      &  0.01 \\
Gnu       & stuffed   & 92.50 \\
Emu       & stuffed   & 33.33 \\
Armadillo & frozen    &  8.99 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd strive for making the header just two rows, smashing it so its depth is not seen.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\smashedcell}[2]{%
  \smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}#1@{}}#2\end{tabular}}%
}

\begin{document}

1. booktabs example: Last column head fits on single line

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{}llr@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Item} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-2}
Animal & Description & Price (\$)\\
\midrule
Gnat      & per gram  & 13.65 \\
          & each      &  0.01 \\
Gnu       & stuffed   & 92.50 \\
Emu       & stuffed   & 33.33 \\
Armadillo & frozen    &  8.99 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

2. Modification: Last column head requires 3 lines

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{}llr@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Item} & \smashedcell{c}{Price in\\Dollars}\\
\cmidrule(r){1-2}
Animal & Description & \\
\midrule
Gnat      & per gram  & 13.65 \\
          & each      &  0.01 \\
Gnu       & stuffed   & 92.50 \\
Emu       & stuffed   & 33.33 \\
Armadillo & frozen    &  8.99 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if what I'm doing here is right, pls strike if not.

Both answers to my question work, and gave me what I needed, but it took me many hours over several days to understand them. Here is what I needed to learn.

The TeX Book C18 Fine Points of Mathematics Typing: \smash ``makes the height and depth zero.''

C11 Boxes ``TeX doesn't have any idea where the ink will go---only the output device knows this.''

TeX works with boxes that have a reference point, a baseline, a height, and a depth. Boxes for letters, rules, etc are joined to form lines of text, which are vertically to create a page of text.

The height (depth) of a line of text is the max of the heights (depths) of the heights (depths) of the boxes concatenated, so my three line heading kicks up the height of the line containing it by a factor of about 3.

\smash changes the height and depth to zero. TeX, oblivious to the content of the heading box, leaves the height of the line containing it to what the height would be without it. This solves my problem.